# Convert Comma-separated Values Into Tags React Native with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I want to convert comma-separated values into tags. In fact I already have a good part done, but I have a problem. the tags come "added" with the previous ones. If I type in the input "ex1,ex2", the tags "ex1" and "ex1,ex2" will be created, but the tags that should be created are "ex1" and "ex2". look: [image: look].

this is my input:

```
<Input
  onChangeText={(text: string) => handleTagChange(text)}
  onKeyPress={handleTagKey}
  value={inputTag}
/>
```

and here is the functions:

```
  const handleTagChange = (text: string) => {setInputTag(text);}
  const handleTagKey = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>) => 
  {
    const { key } = event.nativeEvent;
    const trimmedInput = inputTag.trim();

    if(key === ',' && trimmedInput.length && !tags.includes(trimmedInput)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setTags((prev) => [...prev, trimmedInput]);
    }
  }
```

I thought it would be enough to set an empty string in the input value after setTags (setInputTag("")), but apparently it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you?

```
setTags(trimmedInput.split(","));
```

you must first remove the last comma

Comment: I have already tried this, but the problem is that the input is not cleared at every comma.